# JavaScript Progress bar don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code didn't work with me just one work and when i remove script tag from html to external file didn't work i need need help to all record work and move it to external file.....................................

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var valuee = document.getElementById("bar").value;
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0%</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="bar" name="bar" value="60" />
</div>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0%</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="bar" name="bar" value="60" />
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: where is move() function ?

Comment: What's not working?  And why not use a proper `<progress>` element?

Comment: setInterval() takes millisecond as an argument. So let it be 10*1000 for 10 seconds interval. Also move your frame() out of dom ready. Just a guess!

Comment: Why you use id several time ids used one time change it to class or each div with different id

Comment: i need it auto load with out button

Comment: please i need answer..

Comment: I tested your code, the function seems to be working fine! what's not working?!

Comment: multi bar not work just first bar work

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var valuee = document.getElementById("bar").value;
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }

  var elem_1 = document.getElementById("myBar_1");
  var valuee_1 = document.getElementById("bar_1").value;
  var width_1 = 0;
  var id_1 = setInterval(frame_1, 10);

  function frame_1() {
    if (width_1 >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id_1);
    } else {
      width_1++;
      elem_1.style.width = width_1 + '%';
      elem_1.innerHTML = width_1 * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress,
#myProgress_1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar,
#myBar_1 {
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0%</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="bar" name="bar" value="60" />
</div>

<div id="myProgress_1">
  <div id="myBar_1">0%</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="bar_1" name="bar" value="60" />
</div>

<br>
<button>Click Me</button>
```